How to connect to local IP via Wireguard VPN?
We have an actually simple VPN setup:
Data Logger ====== Router (VPN server) | ===(internet)=== PC

We are using this Wireguard configuration on the router:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...private key
Address = 192.168.115.201/24
DNS = 192.168.115.2
DNS = fritz.box

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...key
PresharedKey = ...key
AllowedIPs = 192.168.115.0/24,0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = [some hash].myfritz.net:[some port]
PersistentKeepalive = 25

I do not get this line: AllowedIPs = 192.168.115.0/24,0.0.0.0/0: 0.0.0.0/0 means everything anyway, right? So why the first range 192.168.115.0/24?
But apart from that:
how can I connect to the local IP, the data logger via internet, but in the same VPN?
When I am trying this from the PC: http://192.168.x.x:80, I am getting a timeout. Although there is running a service on port 80 and it can be used in the local net (router, data logger, more machines...).
What am I doing wrong with Wireguard?

It appears you have the same subnet inside the VPN and on the physical network. This isn’t a good setup, especially with WireGuard.

@DanielB So something like Address = 10.10.10.1/32 on the router (Wireguard config) might help? Or Address = 10.10.10.0/24 instead?

Somewhat like this, but you cannot unilaterally change this. All peers need to agree. The WireGuard config you have appears to have been generated by an AVM FRITZ!Box router. I’m not familiar with setting up WireGuard on these devices, so I cannot offer further assistance, sorry.

I can reply after 5th of August due to vacations.
